# Navigation Drawer items repeating

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer, android-viewholder

I am using a navigation drawer with the listview layout. The items to be populated in the listview are textviews, radiobuttons and checkboxes. The xml layout file is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:gravity="center" />

<RadioGroup 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/radio_group" >

<RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/rbs1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="Male"/>

<RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/rbs2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="Female"/>

<RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/rbs3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="All"
    android:checked="true"/>

</RadioGroup>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="Experience"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/cbs1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="1 yr"/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/cbs2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text=">1 yr"/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/cbs3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text=">2 yr"/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/cbs4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text=">5 yr"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For this am setting an Adapter as

```
listView.setAdapter(new DrawerAdapter(this,R.layout.draw_list_item));
```

The code for adapter is below.

```
package com.example.navdrawer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
private Context context;
private int drawListItem;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
public DrawerAdapter(Context context, int drawListItem) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.drawListItem = drawListItem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return drawListItem;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return drawListItem;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return drawListItem;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt1;
    RadioButton rb1;
    RadioButton rb2;
    RadioButton rb3;
    TextView txt2;
    CheckBox cb1;
    CheckBox cb2;
    CheckBox cb3;
    CheckBox cb4;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewHolder = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(drawListItem, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        viewHolder.rb1 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbs1);
        viewHolder.rb2 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbs2);
        viewHolder.rb3 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbs3);
        viewHolder.txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        viewHolder.cb1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbs1);
        viewHolder.cb2 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbs2);
        viewHolder.cb3 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbs3);
        viewHolder.cb4 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbs4);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
    return convertView;
}

}
```

**What i need is i want to display those items in a listview in the navigation drawer. But the problem is that all these items are repeating in the navigation drawer.**
Please help me with a solution. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Do you want "n" items in your ListView with the layout or you just wanna have 1 item? I'm asking because it isn't clear in your code and how the question is written.

Comment: Sorry am new to android. I need "n" no. of items such as textviews, radiobuttons and checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of referencing the same ViewHolder for every view, create a new one in your getView where convertView==null;